# Doctrine migrate lost my data

Tags: doctrine-orm

I used Doctrine migrate for my FosUserBundle and I thought it would add the table on top of the existing tables in my db...
Well, turned out that when I migrated everything got lost now I only have the user table and all the rest of my db is gone...
Is there a way to restore my previous db or is it completely lost?

I still have all my entities, and I tried the below knowing that it doesn't make sense... as I still have the annotation, so I thought it would re-create them with doctrine command (doctrine:generate:entities Acme:xxx) etc...

Any way to restore my data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually the answer to this question was super simple.
Doctrine has some methods to rollback the schema to a specific migration  either by using the reference of the migration or by using some shortcuts such as "first", "prev" etc...

I personally was able to rollback to the initial state i.e. before migration..

here some details :
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/reference/managing_migrations.html#reverting-migrations